# ppm.bat install failed: Can't find any package that provides GD-Graph3d

Tags: perl

Getting an exception while installing Perl package through below command. Running Perl 5.26 on Windows 10.

```
ppm install GD-Graph3d
```

ppm.bat install failed: Can't find any package that provides GD-Graph3d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ActiveState build for GD::Graph3d](https://code.activestate.com/ppm/GD-Graph3d/) fails since Perl 5.24. See also [the patch that ActiveState try to apply](http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86-64int/5.24/2400/W/WA/WADG/GD-Graph3d-0.63.d/log-20160730T080736.txt). Maybe you can install the module by using the `cpan` tool instead?

```
cpan GD::Graph3d
```